# PHP Invalid argument supplied for foreach() with object(SimpleXMLElement)

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, simplexml

Following some questions, I modified my code as follow, but it does not work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
#var_dump($xml);
#exit;
if(!empty($xml)) {
    foreach($xml->answer->result as $result) {
        if (!empty($result)) {
            foreach($result->attributes() as $a => $b) {
                echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if I `exit` after the first `foreach` loop I obtain the desired results, that means that there is indeed something wrong with the empty element. This is the xml to parse:

```
<response>
    <method>keyword.domain.seo</method>
    <answer>
        <result kw="moos im garten" position="47" competition="0" traffic="20" url="https://www.example.org"/>
        <result kw="moos entfernen" position="75" competition="39" traffic="30" url="https://www.example.org"/>
    </answer>
    <date>2018-09-03T15:56:07+02:00</date>
    <credits used="2"/>
</response>
```

Any idea about what I can do?

Comment: I run it locally and didn't get any error - also in your link it run clear - what is exactly the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but someone edits my question changing the meaning I edit it again in order to recover the original meaning. I know that the code in the link works, the problem is that it does not work when I copy and paste it into my program. This is exactly why I'm so puzzled about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue, I'm sure it is not the best solution but at least it works:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($content) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$results = $xml->answer->result;
if(!empty($results))
{
 foreach($results as $result)
 {
   if (!empty($result))
  {
    foreach($result->attributes() as $a => $b)
    {
     echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: So basically what was suggested by the other answer?

Comment: Not really. What must be checked is the $result, not the $xml. The other answer does not work.

Comment: The other answer merely checked `$xml` for safety. Other than that, the code is the same AFAICS.

Comment: Yes, the code of the other answer is the same as the code that I posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
This should work

$content=<<<XML
<response>
<method>keyword.domain.seosssssss</method>
<answer>
<result kw="moos entfernen" position="74" competition="39" traffic="30" url="https://www.gartenbau.org/moos-entfernen-201816621"/>
<result kw="moosentfernundddddddddddddddg" position="93" competition="52" traffic="20" url="https://www.gartenbau.org/moos-entfernen-201816621"/>
</answer>
<date>2018-08-27T15:13:04+02:00</date>
<credits used="2"/>
</response>  
XML;
        $xml=simplexml_load_string($content) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        #var_dump($xml);
        #exit;
        if(!empty($xml))
        {
            foreach($xml->answer->result as $result)
            {
                if (!empty($result))
                {
                    foreach($result->attributes() as $a => $b)
                    {
                        echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```